# How to avoid array symbol in ajax parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var sample=[];
sample.push("one");
sample.push("two");
sample.push("three");

$.ajax({
        url : 'sampleAction',
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
          'message':sample
        },
        success:function(data){

        }
        });
```

It have to pass this like
[image]

But, it is pass with [] symbol, how to avoid this [] symbol
[image]

Comment: This array symbol suggests the key of that array. Like one is on 0th (first) key and so on.

Comment: Why you want to remove that symbol?

Comment: in server side I get this parameter as arraylist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer, If we give  traditional: true, it works

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'sampleAction',
    dataType : 'json',
    type : 'POST',
    data : sample,
    traditional: true,
    success:function(data){
```

}
});

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing data as array, then it should pass with array symbol. For avoid array symbol you have to pass associative object without nested with message key. And in your server side script you need to change accordingly for grab posted data.

```
var sample=();
sample.one = "one";
sample.two = "two";
sample.three = "three";

$.ajax({
        url : 'sampleAction',
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'POST',
        data : sample,
        success:function(data){
  }
});
```

If you pass multiple messages then I am advising you to keep in array format because it is very easy to access it in server side.

Comment: yes i am sending multiple message, but in server side I get that as array lis, not array so I have to avoid [] symbol, previously I tried the same thing that time the parameter send without [] symbol...